# Delphi. Convert Bitmap image to 2D Array

Tags: arrays, delphi, bitmap, 2d, palette

I have a gif image of 80x40 pixels. The color palette of this image consists of a few similar colors that have different numbers in the palette. How can I build a 2d array where the cell at `x,y` will be a number of the color in the palette?

Comment: Direct access to X-th element of Y-th `Scanline` will give you desired index of color table.

Comment: Can anyone explain why this question is put on hold as off-topic?

Comment: It's actually a good question that could have a clear answer if it wasn't blocked by people who probably don't even understand the question. 3 of the closers have never posted any question or answer with a Delphi tag.

Comment: @TLama: Yay, the new closing system on this site works! Thanks for re-opening, mate. Now if only the badge-whoring-JQuery-guru's would get off our Delphi lawn, we'll get somewhere :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TGifImage has such an array built in, so just make use of it:

```
var 
  Gif:TGifImage;
  PaletteIndex : byte;
begin
  Gif := TGifImage.Create;

  // ... load your stuff here ...

  // TGifImage has an Images property, which is probably only interesting if you're dealing with animations, so just take the first image.
  PaletteIndex := Gif.Images[0].Pixels[0,0]; // palette index for top-left pixel 

  // Now, to get the actual TColor for that pixel, you could do this:
  Self.color := Gif.Images[0].ColorMap.Colors[PaletteIndex];

end;
```

Comment: By the way, this might be a good place to show my appreciation to Anders Melander for donating vcl.Imaging.GIFImg.pas

Answer (score -1):

You can load your image into a `TBitmap`. Then you can use the `ScanLine` property of a `TBitmap` class. This indexed property takes a 0 based index of a row and returns a pointer to pixel values for that row. Take a look at [this page](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29173) to learn more about `ScanLine` property.

Comment: This is not what the poster of the question means. He wants to know the index in the color palette, not the index in the scanline.

Comment: Unfortunately scanline do not work properly, but thanks for answer!